# Is the sentence simple or complex or compound?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know how to swim.

Please tell me whether it is simple or complex sentence.

Comment: It's a complex sentence, since it contains the subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) "how to swim".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple sentence is a sentence that consists of only one clause with a single subject and predicate. A compound sentence, on the other hand, is a sentence with more than one independent clause. That in turn implies that a compound sentence consists of more than one subject or predicate. A complex sentence has at least one independent clause plus at least one dependent clause. This also means that a complex sentence has more than one subject/predicate pair. Sources: [**Sentence clause structure**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure) (from Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia) and [**Independent and Dependent Clauses**](https://www.aims.edu/student/online-writing-lab/grammar/independent-vs-dependent).

For example:

> I know you.

This is a simple sentence because it consists of only one clause and there are only one subject and predicate in it.

> I know you didn't do that.

This one is a compound sentence because by definition a compound sentence is one that consists of more than one independent clause. *I know* is the first independent clause with its own subject/predicate pair and *you didn't do that* is the second independent clause with its own subject/predicate pair.

> I know this because he said that to me.

This sentence is a complex sentence because it contains one independent clause, *I know this*, and one dependent clause, *because he said that to me*. *because he said that to me* is a dependent clause because it entirely depends on *I know this* and from a grammatical perspective can't stand on its own as a complete thought (*Because he said that to me...* what?).

But your case is very simple. How many subject/predicate pairs does your sentence have? I see only one: *I* being the subject and *know how to swim* the predicate. That's just one clause and there are no other clauses. And that's exactly what makes it a simple sentence. Therefore, *I know how to swim* is a simple sentence.

Comment: Dear sir, I have a doubt about this sentence "I know you didn't do that" if it is complex or compound. You stated that it was a compound sentence. But my knowledge says that it is a complex one. Can you please let me clear?

Comment: I expanded my answer a little bit.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with that. "How to swim" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) as complement of "know", so it's a complex sentence.